# Querying MongoDB for range of data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to query a range of data that is not organized by months, but does have ordinal values. I have 13 numbered documents in a given year per person (data simplified):

```
{ "Year" : 2015, "Pts" : 92, "Week" : 1 },
{ "Year" : 2015, "Pts" : 110.3, "Week" : 2 },
{ "Year" : 2015, "Pts" : 104.2, "Week" : 3 },
{ "Year" : 2015, "Pts" : 130.9, "Week" : 4 },
{ "Year" : 2015, "Pts" : 129, "Week" : 5 },
{ "Year" : 2016, "Pts" : 90, "Week" : 1 },
{ "Year" : 2016, "Pts" : 110.5, "Week" : 2 },
{ "Year" : 2016, "Pts" : 106, "Week" : 3 },
{ "Year" : 2016, "Pts" : 150.4, "Week" : 4 },
{ "Year" : 2016, "Pts" : 110, "Week" : 5 },
{ "Year" : 2017, "Pts" : 86.2, "Week" : 1 },
{ "Year" : 2017, "Pts" : 120.2, "Week" : 2 },
{ "Year" : 2017, "Pts" : 111, "Week" : 3 },
{ "Year" : 2017, "Pts" : 105.5, "Week" : 4 }
{ "Year" : 2017, "Pts" : 95.5, "Week" : 5 }
```

I can't figure out how to grab data from week 3, 2015 through week 3, 2017, for example. When I use the following match pattern, it will only pull weeks 3 and up for all years (weeks 1-2 are missing from the result for 2017 and 2018):

```
        {
            $match: 
            { 
                Week: { $gte: weekStart, $lte: weekEnd },
                Year: { $gte: startYear, $lte: endYear }
            }
        },
```

I've tried using $not to try to exclude documents outside of the range, but I get the error `unknown top level operator: $not`. I've also tried cascading $and statements, but that doesn't work either.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the expected and actual output?

Comment: You have to always put the value of `WEEK` greater (`$gte`) than 1... Something like this `Week: { $gte: 1, $lte: 3}, Year: { $gte: startYear, $lte: endYear }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
$or : [
 { Year: startYear, Week: { $gte: weekStart} },
 { Year: { $gt: startYear, $lt: endYear } },
 { Year: endYear, Week: { $lte: weekEnd } }  
]
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! Took me a couple of minutes to understand, but it totally makes sense.